# Reverse of Yeo Johnson variable transformation done by preprocess function in caret package to get original Target and predicted values

Tags: machine-learning, r

I have done a Yeo Johnson transformation by using preprocess from caret package. I have predicted the target variable using linear regression. Now, I would like to reverse the transformation for both the target and the predicted values.

I know this question has been answered before, but I still could not solve my problem. This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973207/revert-transformation-preprocess-caret) and [here](https://rdrr.io/github/jknowles/ModelEWS/src/R/exportPrep.R).

I could not modify it for Yeo Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is an elegant caret solution, but VGAM offers what you are looking for, an inverse of the yeo-jhonson transformation : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.0-3/topics/yeo.johnson.